# Instance deployment failed to install Django application dependencies

Tags: python, django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy my Django app with MySql database into AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Following the official AWS tutorial, after running the command eb deploy I receive the following:

```
Creating application version archive "app-a676-230715_151203074474".
Uploading training_centre/app-a676-230715_151203074474.zip to S3. This may take a while.
Upload Complete.
2023-07-15 07:12:36    INFO    Environment update is starting.      
2023-07-15 07:12:39    INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).
2023-07-15 07:12:45    ERROR   Instance deployment failed to install application dependencies. The deployment failed.
2023-07-15 07:12:45    ERROR   Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.
2023-07-15 07:12:49    ERROR   [Instance: i-0cd43d89a29ebb953] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error..
2023-07-15 07:12:50    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2023-07-15 07:12:50    ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-0cd43d89a29ebb953'. Aborting the operation.
2023-07-15 07:12:50    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.        
                                                                      
ERROR: ServiceError - Failed to deploy application.
```

Here is the output of eb logs:

```
============= i-0cd43d89a29ebb953 ==============
----------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-engine.log
----------------------------------------
      Command 'pkg-config --exists mariadb' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.p
y", line 351, in <module>
          main()
        File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.p
y", line 333, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.p
y", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)      

File "/tmp/pip-build-env-098fsfb8/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in 
get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-098fsfb8/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 323, in 
_get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-098fsfb8/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 338, in 
run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 154, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 48, in get_config_posix
        File "<string>", line 27, in find_package_name
      Exception: Can not find valid pkg-config name.
      Specify MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS and MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS env vars manually
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.1.2
[notice] To update, run: python3.11 -m pip install --upgrade pip

2023/07/15 06:48:18.811452 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [InstallDependency]. St
op running the command. Error: fail to install dependencies with requirements.txt file with error Command /bin/sh -c /v
ar/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:  error: subpr
ocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [25 lines of output]
      Trying pkg-config --exists mysqlclient
      Command 'pkg-config --exists mysqlclient' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      Trying pkg-config --exists mariadb
      Command 'pkg-config --exists mariadb' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.p
y", line 351, in <module>
          main()
        File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.p
y", line 333, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.p
y", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-098fsfb8/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in 
get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-098fsfb8/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 323, in 
_get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-098fsfb8/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 338, in 
run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 154, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 48, in get_config_posix
        File "<string>", line 27, in find_package_name
      Exception: Can not find valid pkg-config name.
      Specify MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS and MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS env vars manually
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.1.2
[notice] To update, run: python3.11 -m pip install --upgrade pip
 

2023/07/15 06:48:18.811455 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
2023/07/15 06:48:18.811558 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status"
:"FAILURE","msg":"Engine execution has encountered an error.","returncode":1,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment fail
ed to install application dependencies. The deployment failed.","timestamp":1689403698811,"severity":"ERROR"},{"msg":"I
nstance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.","timestamp":1689403698811,"severity":"ERROR"}]}]}

2023/07/15 06:48:18.812274 [INFO] Platform Engine finished execution on command: app-deploy

2023/07/15 06:48:45.219879 [INFO] Starting...
2023/07/15 06:48:45.219923 [INFO] Starting EBPlatform-PlatformEngine
2023/07/15 06:48:45.219950 [INFO] reading event message file
2023/07/15 06:48:45.220103 [INFO] Engine received EB command cfn-hup-exec

2023/07/15 06:48:45.318145 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us
-west-2:942392442423:stack/awseb-e-vsht4styb9-stack/a7d3e8a0-1d61-11ee-856a-0615c1c0d2a7 -r AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --reg
ion us-west-2
2023/07/15 06:48:45.701575 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us
-west-2:942392442423:stack/awseb-e-vsht4styb9-stack/a7d3e8a0-1d61-11ee-856a-0615c1c0d2a7 -r AWSEBBeanstalkMetadata --re
gion us-west-2
2023/07/15 06:48:46.042549 [INFO] checking whether command tail-log is applicable to this instance...
2023/07/15 06:48:46.042562 [INFO] this command is applicable to the instance, thus instance should execute command
2023/07/15 06:48:46.042565 [INFO] Engine command: (tail-log)

2023/07/15 06:48:46.042614 [INFO] Executing instruction: GetTailLogs
2023/07/15 06:48:46.042617 [INFO] Tail Logs...
2023/07/15 06:48:46.042864 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c tail -n 100 /var/log/eb-engine.log


----------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-hooks.log
----------------------------------------


(END)
```

I've tried:

1. to check if mysqlclient is installed globally and in my virtual environment (ok)
2. to check if mysql package is in my pythonpath
3. pkg-config is installed (ok)
4. running pkg-config --exists mysql in my local terminal, no output which i'm assuming is positive
5. as suggested, set variables:
   export MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.33_3/include" (path to the mysql library)
   export MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.33_3/lib -lmysqlclient" (to no result)
6. reinstalling mysql (to no result)

I'm relatively new to Django and web app deployment so I would much appreciate help or any hints to solve this issue because i've been hitting this wall for a coulple of weeks :-)

Comment: What you verify in your local terminal won't affect the deployment process that occurs on the Elastic Beanstalk environment...

Comment: from what I understand, it zips the archive of my project with all the dependencies and unzips the archive in the EB environment on the server. is it possible that the issue has been carried from local environment into the server? As I said, I'm new to the topic and still trying to learn.